# Delete some data from a .txt file and then store the rest into two lists..

Tags: python, io

I have data stored in a .txt file...

```
Subset 1    1   350.000 0.096
Subset 1    2   351.000 0.095
Subset 1    3   352.000 0.095
Subset 1    4   353.000 0.097
Subset 1    5   354.000 0.096
Subset 1    6   355.000 0.095
Subset 1    7   356.000 0.097
Subset 1    8   357.000 0.094
Subset 1    9   358.000 0.091
Subset 1    10  359.000 0.091
Subset 1    11  360.000 0.091
Subset 1    12  361.000 0.092
Subset 1    13  362.000 0.091
Subset 1    14  363.000 0.089
Subset 1    15  364.000 0.089
Subset 1    16  365.000 0.090
```

And I want to use only the values `350, 351...` and `0.096, 0.95,...` . So I need in the first place to delete all the `Subset 1`  and number `1,2,3,4...` and then store `350, 351...` and `0.096, 0.95,...` in two different lists in order to plot them.

What I tried to do is something like:

```
import io
# Load the txt file
text_file = io.open("/home/stagiaire/Bureau/01.Dark Skin.txt","r", 
encoding = "utf-16")   
# Read the lines and then strip 
lines = text_file.readlines()
li = lines.strip(',')
# Delete "susbset1" by replacing it with nothing...
nkia = lines.replace("Subset 1","")
```

But it doesn't work...Any suggestions on how I can do it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to apply string modifications to lists. I could fix your code, but let's take a more elegant (and one-line) approach:

I would read the line & split it (without arguments so it acts like `awk`, it considers the field separator as "one or more spaces or tabulations"), keep only the 2 last fields and convert them to float, all in a nested list comprehension:

```
coords = [[float(x) for x in l.split()[-2:]] for l in text_file]
```

that gives me this list of couples:

```
[[350.0, 0.096], [351.0, 0.095], [352.0, 0.095], [353.0, 0.097], [354.0, 0.096], [355.0, 0.095], [356.0, 0.097], [357.0, 0.094], [358.0, 0.091], [359.0, 0.091], [360.0, 0.091], [361.0, 0.092], [362.0, 0.091], [363.0, 0.089], [364.0, 0.089], [365.0, 0.09]]
```

if you *really* need 2 lists, after that, extract them with list comprehensions as well:

`[c[0] for c in coords]` and `[c[1] for c in coords]`

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

here is one way to do it:

```
import io
# Load the txt file
text_file = io.open("/home/stagiaire/Bureau/01.Dark Skin.txt","r", 
encoding = "utf-16")
# Output lists
list1 = []
list2 = []
# Read the lines and then make lists 
for line in text_file.readlines():
    segments = line.split()
    list1.append(segments[-1])
    list2.append(segments[-2])
```

Comment: I would drop `for line in text_file.readlines()` for `for line in text_file`: no need to read the lines at once (saves memory).